# fabric js sendBackwards issue

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

If I use

```
canvas.sendToBack(object)
```

then it creates issue. I have created in demo with fabric js which is creating issue for me, have a look

http://jsfiddle.net/QUEsT/2/

If you try to move image in canvas then you'll get the error in console.

I'm also facing this issue in latest version.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `canvas.sendToBack(img)` the variable img is undefined.
fabric.Image.fromURL is async.

I've updated your jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/rBNNU/1/